# I am using MIME::Lite::TT to send mail with perl. How to save the mail locally before sending

Tags: perl, email, mime

Template

```html
 <html>
 <body>

 <strong>Hi [% first_name %]</strong>,

 <p>
 This is to confirm your purchase of $ [% amt_due %].
 </p>

 <p>
 Thank you!
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>

   `$params{first_name} = 'Frank';
    $params{last_name}  = 'Wiles';
    $params{amt_due}    = '24.99';
    my $msg = MIME::Lite::TT::HTML->new(
        From        =>  'admin@example.com',
        To          =>  'frank@example.com',
        Subject     =>  'Your recent purchase',
        Template    =>  {
                            text    =>  'test.txt.tt',
                            html    =>  'test.html.tt',
                            },
        TmplOptions =>  \%options,
        TmplParams  =>  \%params,
 );
```

How to save the mail locally before sending. It is having template as html which is populated with params and a pdf attachment.
Is it possible to save the Template with populated values.

Comment: Show us your code what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MIME::Lite::TT](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite::TT) is just a preprocessor; calling `MIME::Lite::TT->new` returns a normal `MIME::Lite` object.  Just save that object in whatever way you like.

For example, you can [print it to a filehandle](https://metacpan.org/pod/MIME::Lite#Print-a-message-to-a-filehandle):

```
my $email = MIME::Lite::TT->new(...);
$email->print(\*STDOUT);
$email->send;
```

Comment: @quorious, that should be the complete MIME message including the attachments.

Comment: Yes right.
I am also attaching a template and passing the values from script.
Is is possible to save the populated template?

Comment: As I thought I had explained, the template processing happens during `MIME::Lite::TT->new`.  The object you get back from `new` is a normal `MIME::Lite` email with the template already populated.

Comment: Is it possible to save only template not whole mail?

Comment: Thanks @cjm for all the help.
After some digging I found the solution.
We can get the populated template by  "$$email{data}" .

Answer (score 0):

To print the populated template we can use

```
$$email{data}
```

As $email is a reference to a hash and data is a key to the contents of body of email.
To print the whole mail use the above solution.

Comment: This is breaking encapsulation.  `$email` is a reference to a MIME::Lite object, which happens to be implemented as a hash.  I think you're looking for `$email->data`.

Comment: Yes @cjm and above statement serves that.